# CSS Syntax - How to interpret this?

Tags: css, syntax

I have very little experience with CSS. The following syntax is from bootstrap 3.

```
.table > thead > tr > td.danger,
.table > tbody > tr > td.danger,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.danger,
.table > thead > tr > th.danger,
.table > tbody > tr > th.danger,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.danger,
.table > thead > tr.danger > td,
.table > tbody > tr.danger > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.danger > td,
.table > thead > tr.danger > th,
.table > tbody > tr.danger > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.danger > th {
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #eed3d7;
}
```

I was hoping someone could translate this into English for me.

Comment: You should search for more about **CSS Selector**, in this case almost you need to know about is the so-called direct child selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To take the first line as an example

```
.table > thead > tr > td.danger
```

The `.table` is a class named table, the `>` means anything nested directly inside. `thead` is an html element, as is `tr`, while `td.danger` is a combination of a html element `td` with a class `danger`.

So this line means a `td` with the class `danger`, inside of a `tr`, inside of a `thead`, inside of an element with the class `table`.

The `background-color` and `border-color` at the end are the styles being applied to the specified elements with `#f2dede` and `#eed3d7` as their values.

In summary, the overall syntax is as follows:

```
selector {
   style: value;
}
```

And as you can see in the example, you can have multiple selectors separated by commas and multiple styles and values separated by `;` inside the curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

`.table` = element with `class="table"`

`>` = direct child of

`thead` = `thead` elements

`td` = `td` elements

`td.danger` = `td` elements with `class="danger"`

`,` = or

---

`.table > thead > tr > td.danger` = all `td`s with `class="danger"` that are direct children of a `tr` that is a descendant of a `thead` that is a descendant of an element with `class="table"`.

---

The comma (`,`) means or. A simple example:

```
.element1, .element2 {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Per this style definition, all elements with `class=".element1"` or `class=".element2"` will have a black background.

---

A note on the `>`s. If you have the following HTML:

```
<div class="top-div">
    <div class="sub-div">
        <img src="foo.png">
    </div>
    <img src="bar.png">
</div>
```

and use this CSS:

```
.top-div > img {
    // Styles here
}
```

only the image with `src="bar.png"` will be styled.

If, however, you use this CSS (no `>`):

```
.top-div img {
    // Styles here
}
```

both `<img>` tags will be styled.

Answer (score -2):

Its basically the same as saying this:

Not really, but very close... except the `>`'s mean its nested directly inside.

```
.table thead tr td.danger {
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #eed3d7;
}
.table tbody tr td.danger {
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #eed3d7;
}
.table tfoot tr td.danger {
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #eed3d7;
}
.table thead tr th.danger {
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #eed3d7;
}
.table body tr th.danger {
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #eed3d7;
}
.table tfoot tr td.danger {
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #eed3d7;
}
.table thead tr.danger td {
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #eed3d7;
}
.table tbody tr.danger td {
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #eed3d7;
}
.table tbody tr.danger td {
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #eed3d7;
}
.table thead tr.danger th {
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #eed3d7;
}
.table tbody tr.danger th {
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #eed3d7;
}
.table tbody tr.danger th {
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #eed3d7;
}
```